# Storing and reading array of own classes into a plist?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to store a list of own classes into a plist. For that I also found a similar question already answered, but I still do not succeed doing this.

My code:

My Class:

```
class Bookmark: NSObject {

    var sName:String="";
    var sTextPosition:String="";  // beim Text scrollpos

    init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        self.sName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String;
        self.sTextPosition = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("textposition")as! String;
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(sName, forKey:"name");
        aCoder.encodeObject(sTextPosition, forKey:"textposition");
    }

}
```

My Code for storing an array of bookmarks:

```
 var bookmark1:Bookmark=Bookmark(); // <--"Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call".
        bookmark1.sName="myname";
        bookmark1.sTextPosition="100";

        let listofbookmarks:[Bookmark];
        listofbookmarks.append(bookmark1)



        let fileManager = (NSFileManager.defaultManager())
        let directorys : [String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]

        if (directorys != nil){
            let directories:[String] = directorys!;
            let pathToFile = directories[0]; //documents directory
            let plistfile = "BookmarkArray.plist"
            let plistpath = pathToFile.stringByAppendingPathComponent(plistfile);

            if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(plistpath){

                println("Declaring cocoaArray")
                var cocoaArray : NSArray = listofbookmarks;
                cocoaArray.writeToFile(plistpath, atomically: true)

            }
        }
```

I stuck in creating a Bookmark : `var bookmark1:Bookmark=Bookmark();`
"Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call".

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only initializer that you have in your object is `init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)` so when the object is being created it's assuming that you are calling that method and are missing an `NSCoder` object.

You also need to use `NSKeyedArchiver` to perform the serialization and write the data to storage. `NSKeyedUnArchiver` performs the reverse. To use them you adhere to the `NSCoding` protocol. You also need to mark your class as `@objc` so that it can be deserialized properly.

Here's a version of your code with an initializer method for creation without a `NSCoder`, plus a few other fixes:

```
import Foundation

@objc(Bookmark) class Bookmark: NSObject, NSCoding { // <- added @objc and NSCoding
  var sName = ""
  var sTextPosition = ""  // beim Text scrollpos

  init(name:String, position:String) { // <- new initializer
    self.sName = name
    self.sTextPosition = position
  }

  required init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { // <- removed ! to adhere to NSCoding protocol
    if let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as? String {
      sName = name
    }
    if let position = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("textposition") as? String {
      sTextPosition = position
    }
  }

  func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) { // <- removed ! to adhere to NSCoding protocol
    aCoder.encodeObject(sName, forKey:"name")
    aCoder.encodeObject(sTextPosition, forKey:"textposition")
  }
}

var listofbookmarks = [Bookmark]() // <- needed to create a mutable array instance
listofbookmarks.append(Bookmark(name: "myname", position: "100")) // <- new initializer

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

if let directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String] {
  if !directories.isEmpty {
    let plistpath = directories[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("BookmarkArray.plist")
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(plistpath) {
      NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(listofbookmarks, toFile: plistpath) // <- added serializer
    }
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(plistpath) {
      if let decoded = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(plistpath) as? [Bookmark] {
          println(decoded[0].sName)  // => "myname"
          println(decoded[0].sTextPosition) // => "100"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I guess thats the right way, but it still doesn't store any file. I do not get any syntax error and the app runs through, but there is no file created. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You need to serialize the array with `NSKeyedArchiver` and then save that data. I'll update my answer. I also tweaked the code a bit to make it simpler.

Comment: Perfect. It works. Only 2 additional Questions, if you find the time :-). 1. Howto read the stuff again. I tried now 30 mins with "NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData", but I am to stupid :-) 2. Howto to store this in plain XML and not binary ? I accepted, because the question is answered.

Comment: On a further note, you have to add the `NSCoding` protocol to show that the class can be serialized. You also have to add `@objc(Bookmark)` to properly unarchive the object. Updated.